# public multi-modal single-cell data

Tags: scrnaseq, single-cell

There is a [scRNAseq](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/experiment/html/scRNAseq.html) Bioconductor package with a few different example scRNA-seq datasets. Are there any R packages that offer multiple modalities of single-cell data? For example, hashtags or ADTs or ATAC-seq. I am trying to find something that can be used for testing or for a quick tutorial. Preferably something that is on CRAN or Bioconductor.

Answer (score 5):

These tutorials on [Seurat multimodal](https://satijalab.org/seurat/v3.1/multimodal_vignette.html) data and the wrapper [Seurat data](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat-data) are easy ways to start.

The wrapper has some cite-seq data preinstalled making it easy to work with benchmarked data sets

If you are using Seurat u can just as well have a look at [Signac](https://satijalab.org/signac/) to start working with some sc-atac seq